# Admob interstitial ad freezes app when leaving the app (Android)

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

I've implemented an interstitial ad in my Android game.

It's working alright.
But when i leave the app while it's showing, the app will freeze and become unresponsive when i return.

No problems when i click the [X] of the ad without leaving.

*Example*:

1. Interstitial ad is shown. I click on the Overview button (or i click on the ad itself which takes me the web browser).

[image: Ad is shown]

2. After returning to the app, the app is frozen and clicking on the screen only produces a black screen.

[image: Black screen]

**Code to show the ad.** It's only called when loadAd was successful.

```
public void showAd(Context con) {
    ((SummerBound) con).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {

                if (mInterstitialAd == null) {
                    GooglePlayBlueskied.events.add(SummerBound.EVENT_SHOW_AD_FAILED);
                    Log.e("LOGBLUESKIED", "showAd: mInterstitialAd == null");
                } else {
                    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                        mInterstitialAd.show();
                    } else {
                        GooglePlayBlueskied.events.add(SummerBound.EVENT_SHOW_AD_FAILED);
                        Log.e("LOGBLUESKIED", "showAd: isLoaded = false");
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                GooglePlayBlueskied.events.add(SummerBound.EVENT_SHOW_AD_FAILED);
                Log.e("LOGBLUESKIED", "Exception in showAd: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Logcat:
https://pastebin.com/PfVr3pgy

Exceptions in log:

```
2021-01-30 16:04:30.885 2972-3608/? W/ExifInterface: Invalid image: ExifInterface got an unsupported image format file(ExifInterface supports JPEG and some RAW image formats only) or a corrupted JPEG file to ExifInterface.
    java.io.IOException: Invalid byte order: ffff8950
        at android.media.ExifInterface.readByteOrder(ExifInterface.java:3121)
        at android.media.ExifInterface.isOrfFormat(ExifInterface.java:2437)
        at android.media.ExifInterface.getMimeType(ExifInterface.java:2315)
        at android.media.ExifInterface.loadAttributes(ExifInterface.java:1753)
        at android.media.ExifInterface.<init>(ExifInterface.java:1447)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.d.a.ac.a(SourceFile:4)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.f.b(SourceFile:19)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.d.a.w.a(SourceFile:31)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.d.a.g.a(SourceFile:6)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.b.v.a(SourceFile:13)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.b.m.h(SourceFile:123)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.b.m.a(SourceFile:249)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.b.g.a(SourceFile:38)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.c.o.a(SourceFile:4)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.b.g.a(SourceFile:30)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.b.m.e(SourceFile:82)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.b.m.run(SourceFile:59)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.b.c.d.run(SourceFile:9)


2021-01-30 16:04:36.941 30340-30340/? D/BoundBrokerSvc: onUnbind: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.ads.service.CACHE pkg=com.google.android.gms }
2021-01-30 16:04:37.840 1745-2279/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: a: input svInfo.flags is 8
2021-01-30 16:04:37.840 1745-2279/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: b: input svInfo.flags is 8
2021-01-30 16:04:38.071 5456-5506/com.blueskied.summerbound W/ConnectionTracker: Exception thrown while unbinding
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: ls@365d8cb
        at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1751)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1776)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:741)
        at ci.f(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204714084@20.47.14 (120700-0):1)
        at ci.d(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204714084@20.47.14 (120700-0):2)
        at lt.E(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204714084@20.47.14 (120700-0):9)
        at ld.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204714084@20.47.14 (120700-0):3)
        at ef.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204714084@20.47.14 (120700-0):3)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at iy.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204714084@20.47.14 (120700-0):5)
```

Comment: If you want someone to help you, you have to post a log with crash or part of the code that shows interstitial ad...

Comment: Ok. Code and log added.

Comment: showAd is called from which method?

Comment: also make sure onPause and ondestroy of adview are handled

Comment: showAd is called from C++ through JNI.
I don't deal with any adView object, it's a fullscreen ad (interstitial).
What do i need to do in onPause and onDestroy ?